# Using LabelMe images and annotation xmls to train object detection models

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am exploring multiple different ways to train my object detection model. The bounding box method didnt give good results. I am thinking of using LabelMe to annotate images by drawing polygons around objects. Does it give better accuracy ?

The XMLs generated after drawing polygons in LabelMe are different from the one generated by bounding boxes in LabelImg. How can create a TF record file out of these XMLs ?

Comment: I trained many datasets for the other models using LabelImg, however I am testing the workflow right now of training using LabelMe and training a MASK RCNN model using tensorflow.

it really depends on how you define accuracy, and how you train your dataset, based on the tensorflow testing, using masks is slower and is less accurate. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

you mentioned XMLs, however LabelMe outputs JSON files, I am going through this now and will post a demo or tutorial on this, as the docs are lacking

Comment: @dfresh22, thanks for the response. I have used LabelMe's web interface, have not installed it on my desktop. I am going back to LabelImg now.

Comment: however, I am curious how you did the test and what kind of objects you are testing, cause bounding boxes should yield good results if trained correctly. 
how many samples did you train per each label?

Comment: @dfresh22, I have chosen around 1000 images for each class and trained for 2 classes. I am suspecting it could be due to the nature of images I have chosen. They don't represent a good variety of the class.